# How can I apply numerical gradient in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

By using "compute_gradients" and "apply_gradients" I can modify default gradient in symbolics. But how can I modify gradients in runtime, that is, retrieve the gradients and set them to another numerical value from elsewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: An example is, suppose I have y = x * x and default gradient which autodiff gives is y' = 2 * x. I can modify the symbolic gradient using "apply_gradients" to something like 3 * x. But how can I make it 3 at x = 1, which could only be decided in runtime?

Comment: I think we have been using the experimental `partial_run` for that. It allows you to run the graph to get the gradients, tweak the gradients, then continue running the graph. It's fairly advanced usage.

Comment: You cannot inspect the value of x when building the graph but you can write an op to do so.